# Excessively high disk usage freezes my server

Tags: linux, linux-mint

I have a laptop converted to a Linux Mint server running a variety of services. Recently, it started being unaccessible at random.

The situation seems intermittent. The server is usually blazing fast. I can still ping the server, but any attempt to access its services (ssh, web, etc) takes a prohibitive amount of time.

When I try to access the server with SSH, it can take over 15 minutes before I get to the login screen. The hard drive activity light stays on and the machine is running hotter than usual but not dangerously so. If I reboot the machine, it is super fast for some time, until it randomly becomes unresponsive again, maybe days later.

I have tried using `iotop`, but I've spent the past 45 minutes just waiting for it:

```
user@machine~ $ sudo iotop
[sudo] password for user: debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE
debug3: Received SSH2_MSG_IGNORE

debug2: client_check_window_change: changed
debug2: channel 0: request window-change confirm 0
```

**EDIT** I power cycled the server and took a look at all the logs. These were the last entries in syslog. There were several hundred of identical lines preceding it:

```
Jul 17 20:35:16 t510-mint pulseaudio[2106]: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Warning! Too many connections (64), dropping incoming connection.
Jul 17 20:35:40  pulseaudio[2106]: last message repeated 673 times
Jul 17 20:35:40 t510-mint rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 2106 due to rate-limiting
Jul 17 20:35:41 t510-mint rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 6 messages from pid 2106 due to rate-limiting
Jul 17 20:35:41 t510-mint pulseaudio[2106]: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Warning! Too many connections (64), dropping incoming connection.
Jul 17 20:36:05  pulseaudio[2106]: last message repeated 673 times
Jul 17 20:36:05 t510-mint rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock begins to drop messages from pid 2106 due to rate-limiting
Jul 17 20:36:06 t510-mint rsyslogd-2177: imuxsock lost 6 messages from pid 2106 due to rate-limiting
Jul 17 20:36:06 t510-mint pulseaudio[2106]: [pulseaudio] protocol-native.c: Warning! Too many connections (64), dropping incoming connection.
Jul 17 20:37:19  pulseaudio[2106]: last message repeated 567 times
```

Comment: Logs? Did you check logs? like /var/log/messages or /var/log/dmesg.0 and so on?

Comment: Sounds like a swapping issue. Please [edit] your question and tell us how much RAM and how much swap you have. Also show us the output of `grep swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf`.

Comment: I would love to check the logs, but the system is still inaccessible.

The swappiness settings should be the default ones. However, I have considered checking for memory usage too.

Comment: Also run `top` and look at the VIRT column to see if there's anything that is a lot larger than the size of your RAM.

Comment: I like this command `vmstat 1`. You can leave running in background and paste the most recent lines when it fails?

Comment: I got back home and manually powercycled the server. I am currently running iotop, hoping for the problem to happen while I'm monitoring it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try accessing the system in runlevel 3 for multiuser command line mode and try to clean some space on the / filesystem, while you are at it, it'll be a great idea to get some unused space (if any) for some extra swap. If you already are in runlevel 3, then clean the system at runlevel 1 which will load basic services for you to run diagnostics and/or troubleshoot. The system should become accessible from this runlevel and you should be able to get some logs as well (grep swappiness /etc/sysctl.conf).

Take a look at this post for runlevel info:

[Debian init runlevels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/77334/debian-init-runlevels)

Comment: The filesystem has plenty of space left, so that is not an issue. The grep command returns nothing with those parameters.

Comment: What about the swap space? Do you have enough assigned?

grep SwapTotal /proc/meminfo

Comment: I was able to get the same thing to happen a few seconds ago. There was plenty of RAM left, so it shouldn't be a problem, correct?

Comment: Well, enough RAM doesn't always means that you are OK to go. RAM is always important, but Linux uses swap space too for process buffering. Swap is recommended to be 2x the size of RAM but this is just a suggestion. If you have enough RAM and HDD space, then 1x of swap should be OK.
Something else to check is what the top command gives you when the services are running, try:

top > Shift+f > n. That will give you who's eating RAM when the problem occurs

Comment: Got 8GB of SWAP (and 4GB of RAM), so I assume this is fine?

Comment: As for the services, the system went from 100% fine to unusable in less than 10 seconds, to the point I couldn't even run iotop or top.

Comment: Sounds like a service/process that it's on the startup and starts consuming RAM and resources very quick when it starts. Does the system recovers after sometime or it just hangs forever? What service/software did you install on it?
You should give it a try to the runlevel 1 mode and run a top command to see what's the 'normal' processing of the system without any other software on startup, then compare it against a top redirection from the system when it hangs up and find the guilty process. Once isolated you can remove it from the startup script and check how the system behaves.

Answer (score 0):

Some process(es) went berserk, check what was running when it crashed/froze. Review what is installed/what users have access to remotely. Could be some sort of attack trying to overwhelm the machine (or caused inadvertently by a wannabe attacker trying over and over, perhaps trying passwords at random).

Users requested too much. Check user requests, perhaps limit that.

Choked on trying to process a much too large file somewhere (have some entertaining war stories from way back...). Shouldn't happen unless you are running very low on space.

For *any* network facing machine, check/review what is installed (keep only what is needed, keep up to date!), configurations, security harness (SELinux enabled and enforcing, the "just disable SELinux" recomendation should be a felony)